# Using CStrings in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is there any declaration that is similar to `CStrings` in Objective C? Is `NSString` enough to declare a string?

Is there any other representation similar to `CStrings` in objective C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is NSString enough to declare a string?

Yes.  NSString is the direct equivalent of MFC's CString type, although it, like Java String and C# string has better functionality and is easier to use.

> Is there any other representation similar to CStrings in objective C?

There is also the Core Foundation type [CFString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html).  This is a pure C object used within the C parts of the OS X APIs.  CFString has some slightly better functionality than NSString but is a bit harder to use.  If you are in Objective-C and not straight C or C++, stick with NSString. In any case, NSString and CFString are [toll free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW98). That means that you can use one as the other with just a type cast.

Bottom line: stick with NSString.

Comment: Thanks a lot.You gave a good explanation for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

NSString is fine, it's like CString ;-)

Comment: Thanks septi for conforming it.

Comment: It's like CString but better.  (I'm assuming you mean the MFC CString).  There's also CFString

Comment: @JeremyP:Yeah i mean MFC CString.I am porting the c++ code to objective C.How to define it.NSString* string =@"date \t time \t event id  \t event descriptions".How to declare the same in CFString.

Comment: @Beata:  I've added an answer because the comment format is too restrictive.